# How to fix 'No way to dispatch this command to Redis Cluster because keys have different slots' in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis, redis-cluster

I need to use Redis Cluster in Spring. But I'm getting the following error when I use mget or del on a list of keys: 'No way to dispatch this command to Redis Cluster because keys have different slots'. Showing a part of my Component code using JedisCluster.

It works when I use single key operations but not with multiple keys.

```
/* Component Code */
public class RedisServiceManager {

    @Value("${redis.hosts}")
    String hosts;

    @Autowired
    JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig;

    private JedisCluster jedisCluster;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        List<String> redisHosts = Arrays.asList(hosts.split(","));
        Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNode = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
        redisHosts.forEach(redisHost -> {
            jedisClusterNode.add(new HostAndPort(redisHost, 6379));
        });
        jedisCluster = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNode, jedisPoolConfig);
    }

    // This works
    public String getValueForKey(String key) {
        try {
            return jedisCluster.get(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // This works
    public void delKey(String cacheKey) {
        try {
            jedisCluster.del(cacheKey);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    // This doesn't work
    public List<String> getValuesForAllKeys(String... keys) {
        try {
            return jedisCluster.mget(keys);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    // This doesn't work
    public void delAllKeys(String... keys) {
        try {
            jedisCluster.del(keys);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug or an issue, but is the way how redis cluster works. You can find more details [in the cluster documentation](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec). But don't worry: there is a "trick": you can use hash  [as described here](https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-clustering-best-practices-with-keys/)